# How can I do multiple (double) integral with periodic boundary conditions?

Tags: programming, calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to do a simple double integral

$\int_0^l \left[\int_0^l h^3 h_{xxx}dx\right]dx$

with periodic boundary conditions

$h[0,\tau]=h[l,\tau]$

$h_x[0,\tau]=h_x[l,\tau]$

$h_{xx}[0,\tau]=h_{xx}[l,\tau]$

$h_{xxx}[0,\tau]=h_{xxx}[l,\tau]$

I understand this is a very simple double integral, which could be conducted with integrating by part and periodic boundary conditions. I just want to know how I can tell Mathmatica to implement integration by part and invoking (periodic) boundary conditions. This is my code:

```
Integrate[
Integrate[
h[x, τ]^3*D[h[x, τ], {x, 3}], {x, 0, l},
Assumptions ->
  l > 0 && l ∈ Reals && τ > 0 && τ ∈ Reals &&
  h[0, τ] == h[l, τ] &&
  Derivative[1, 0][h][0, τ] == Derivative[1, 0][h][l, τ] && 
  Derivative[2, 0][h][0, τ] == Derivative[2, 0][h][l, τ] && 
  Derivative[3, 0][h][0, τ] == Derivative[3, 0][h][l, τ]
  ], {x, 0, l},
Assumptions ->
l > 0 && l ∈ Reals && τ > 0 && τ ∈ Reals &&
h[0, τ] == h[l, τ] &&
Derivative[1, 0][h][0, τ] == Derivative[1, 0][h][l, τ] &&
Derivative[2, 0][h][0, τ] == Derivative[2, 0][h][l, τ] && 
Derivative[3, 0][h][0, τ] == Derivative[3, 0][h][l, τ]
] // FullSimplify
```

It does not give me a meaningful answer. I am not sure if the syntax is correct especially for the `Assumptions` and multiple integration.

Comment: `Integrate` cannot do the inner integral and returns it unintegrated.  Apparently, it then treats the returned inner integral as a constant in doing the outer integral.

Comment: It looks like your function `h `is unknown, is it? If yes, I wonder, what do you expect to obtain? If it is known, why do not you define it?

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, yes, the function h is unknown. I want to obtain a more simple form, specifically, a polynominal including only up to 1-st derivative of h with respect to x and excluding integration.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, such is the fact. The problem now is how can Mathematica do multiple integral with respect to one independent variable? BTW, why there is a constant just "1" heading the "answer" MMA spit? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, it is not a one but a lower case L, the result of integrating a constant (the inner integral returned unintegrated) over `{0, l}`.  It may be that Mathematica simply is unable to address your problem.  Despite its enormous power, Mathematica certainly cannot do everything.  (For instance, it cannot do integro-differential equations.)

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Thanks for your explanation, especially for the example which kind of equation will overwhelm Mathematica :). However, I believe Mathematica can do multiple integral with respect to one independent variable. So I will seek and wait for the method how to tell it to do that...

Comment: I may have been unclear in my earlier Comments.  Your inner expression is an definite integral over {0, l} and, therefore, is not a function of `x`, no matter what its integrand may be.  So, the outer integral always will yield the factor `l`, because its integrand is a constant with respect to `x`.  Consider, for instance, the simpler `Integrate[Integrate[h[x]*D[h[x], x], {x, 0, l}], {x, 0, l}]`.  Mathematica cannot solve even this simple inner integral but correctly reduces the outer one to `l`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey,thanks, clear explanation!